# MSTest Parameterization of Tests - how do I name the test case?

Tags: c#, testing, parameters, mstest, naming

I want to be able to name my test cases. How do I do that?

```
[TestClass]
public class RegressionTests
{
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.systemError, false, 110, SystemValidations.SystemErrorText)]
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.proposalError, false, 22, SystemValidations.PTErrorText)]
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.financeError, false, 22, SystemValidations.FTErrorText)]
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.noFinance, false, 53, SystemValidations.noFinanceErrorText)]
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.annualMileage, false, 22, SystemValidations.annualMileageErrorText)]
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.loanAmountBoth, false, 33, SystemValidations.loanAmountBothErrorText)]
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.proposalError, false, 22, SystemValidations.PTErrorText)]
    [DataTestMethod]
    
    public void ValidationTests(string requestType, bool valid, int errorCode, string errorText)
    {
        TestSetup.TestSetupMethod(requestType, valid, errorCode, errorText);
    }
```

Comment: I think people are confused by the title of your question. Naming things is subjective, and therefore opinion-based (which is off-topic for this site). Can you clarify what you mean by naming the test case? Maybe provide an example of what you want to name it, or where you expect this name to show up? This might be an answerable question, but we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear whether your question is about naming the test method or changing the name of the test as it appears in Visual Studio Test Explorer. I'm going to assume you want to change the name of the test in Test Explorer, or the test result files generated when running tests.

---

The DataRowAttribute class has a property named "[DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#properties)", which you can use to customize the name of that variation of the test:

```
[TestClass]
public class RegressionTests
{
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow(SendProposalRequest.systemError, false, 110, SystemValidations.SystemErrorText, DisplayName = "System error")]
    //                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...
    public void ValidationTests(string requestType, bool valid, int errorCode, string errorText)
```

The basic format for using this is:

```
[DataRow(arg1, arg2, ... argN, DisplayName = "Your custom name here")]
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```